# Create new column base upon existing column in NuShell

Tags: nushell

I am new to NuShell and would like to create a quick way to locate my files by their "tags", which are in the filename.  This is the method used by [tagspaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/).  For instance, using the **ls** command my directory might look like this:

| # | name | type | size | modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Documents | dir | 134 b | a week ago |
| 1 | Fake doc1 [Fake clj client project1].txt | file | 15 B | 2 weeks ago |
| 2 | Downloaded_doc.pdf | file | 150 B | 4 weeks ago |
| 3 | Fake doc2 [Important :12/31/2022 client project1].txt | file | 365 B | 1 week ago |

However, I would like to create a new column labeled "tags" and only include the tags (the terms inside the brackets) from the name column.  I think this regex will take the bracketed information (includes brackets at this point, which I don't want: **\[.+?\]**

I would like the end result to look like this:

| # | name | tags | type | size | modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Documents |  | dir | 134 b | a week ago |
| 1 | Fake doc1 [Fake clj client project1].txt | Fake clj client project1 | file | 15 B | 2 weeks ago |
| 2 | Downloaded_doc.pdf |  | file | 150 B | 4 weeks ago |
| 3 | Fake doc2 [Important :12/31/2022 client project1].txt | Important :12/31/2022 client project1 | file | 365 B | 1 week ago |

What would be the best way of doing this?  I have read the docs but need to see more real life code before I really "get" this shell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ls | insert tags {|item|
    if $item.name =~ '\[.*\]' {
      $item.name | str replace '.*\[(.*)\].*' '$1'
    }
  } | move tags --after name

╭───┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────┬──────┬─────────┬───────────────╮
│ # │                         name                          │                 tags                  │ type │  size   │   modified    │
├───┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼─────────┼───────────────┤
│ 0 │ Documents                                             │                                       │ dir  │ 4.0 KiB │ 9 minutes ago │
│ 1 │ Downloaded_doc.pdf                                    │                                       │ file │     0 B │ 9 minutes ago │
│ 2 │ Fake doc1 [Fake clj client project1].txt              │ Fake clj client project1              │ file │     0 B │ 9 minutes ago │
│ 3 │ Fake doc2 [Important :12-31-2022 client project1].txt │ Important :12-31-2022 client project1 │ file │     0 B │ 8 minutes ago │
╰───┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴─────────┴───────────────╯
```

- The `insert` built-in creates a new column
- It takes a closure, which runs on each item in the table.  The value of `$item` becomes each directory entry.
- All we really care about here is the `$item.name`.  First we test it to see if it has tags in the `[]` format.
- If it does, we set the `tags` column value to the text matching inside the `[]`.

  This might be a bit tricky to parse at first, but keep in mind that the last value (in this case the *only* value) in the closure or block is essentially its "return value".  There's no need to `echo` or `return` it, since Nushell has implicit output.

  For instance, if that line was simply the string "Has tags", then the `tags` column would include *that* string (rather than the actual matched tags) for each directory entry that matched the `if` statement.
- Finally, after the `tags` column has been inserted, we move it directly after the `name` column.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much.  I will now create a custom command based upon this answer.